# Visio TV attached with HDMI to iMac zombie

Tags: imac, hdmi

I've connected my Vizio TV with HDMI and thunderbolt (USB3?) to my iMac. It seems to work pretty well. But when I turn off the TV, the Mac still thinks that it's connected and behaves in dual monitor mode. Is there a setting, an app or a trick that would overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TV is not actually turned off, it’s in standby.  And since many consumer electronics companies utilize the [CEC signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) over HDMI so *other* devices can turn it on/off, the Mac is interpreting that it’s still on.

You’ll have to disconnect your Mac or turn off the monitor from the mains themselves.

**Possible solution**

I’ve been looking at a product from a Pulse-8 that claims to have a [USB CEC adapter](https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter) that allows you to control the CEC signaling from a computer.  I haven’t tested it for a number of reasons not limited to many other projects, proximity of my iMac an my living room TV, priority, etc.  However, since it “intercepts” the HDMI signal and overrides the CEC signaling, it *may* solve the problem.  I’m not saying it does, but it may be worth looking into.

Additional solution - there is an “[HDMI CEC-less](http://radnex.us/HDMI-CEC-less)” cable that doesn’t have the CEC signaling pins - this too, could solve your issue.

Comment: Let me know if either works - especially the cable.  It’s cheap and has a 30 day return so the risk is super low.

Comment: The worry with that cable is that it might otherwise not be as good, image quality or otherwise. Any way to tell?

Comment: Is there a way to tell MacOS to ignore the second screen and operate as if it is not there? @Allan?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Windows can do this, but macOS won’t.  There may be a 3rd party utility, but I, personally don’t know of one.